# Android Emulator Push but files wont appear

Tags: android, adb, emulation

So I am trying to push a .cer file onto my android emulator to test https communications. When I push the file (or any file for that matter, I tried a jpg) it says it completed and browsing the emulators files in adb it says that the file exists in the sdcard (/sdcard/) or download folder (/storage/sdcard/Download/) but when I browse to it on the actual emulator they do not appear.

How can I make these files appear?

**EDIT**

The commands I use to push the certificate onto the device:

```
adb push MyCertificate.cer /storage/sdcard/Download/
```

This works on an actual phone but on the android emulator the file doesn't seem to appear. But on the emulator I can't see them in the download folder, However if I go to Settings>storage>sdcard/misc then it says it is there! But I cant find anyway to use it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exect command you type.

Comment: Did you set up your sd card to be a removable storage or a part of the OS storage? that might be the case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not exactly an answer,but no one seems to be answering so, I got around this by loading the .cer file into my apk's assets and then programatically installing it using the KeyChain api.

Comment: Yeh, it isn't an answer - dislike (

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to run the next command?

`adb -s $device shell am broadcast -W android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH`

`-s $device` - if you have more than one attached device in your system.
If seems like it's working on some emu/OS versions, at least for me.

The another possible solution is to reboot the target device.